# awk launchctl output and pipe to another command

Tags: bash, shell

How do I pipe the command out put of

```
gent$ launchctl list | grep 'com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice'
9222    0       com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.B79F217D-5158-48BB-BA4C-7089CA29ACBB
```

```
$ launchctl list | grep 'com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice' | awk -F '   ' '{print $2}'
```

expected output

```
com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.B79F217D-5158-48BB-BA4C-7089CA29ACBB
```

I eventually want to feed that output to
to `launchctl remove <output from above>`

I been using awk but the space separating is different length. Any suggestions?

Comment: Could you please post your awk command in your question along with expected output to make it more clear, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You may use this pipeline to get the `service-name` printed from `awk` and then feed it into `xargs` command to have it run as `launchctl remove gui/501/<service-name>`:

```sh
launchctl list |
awk 'index($NF, "com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice") {print $NF}' |
xargs -I % launchctl remove 'gui/501/%'
```